# Matching similar (momentJs) dates between two arrays of (momentJs) dates into a new array

Tags: reactjs, arrays, date, highcharts, momentjs

In Short: I'm looking for all the dates in `firstDateList` that have a matching date in `secondDateList` within some threshold (which can differ from seconds to minutes) ([Thanks for @gloo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72619476/matching-similar-momentjs-dates-between-two-arrays-of-momentjs-dates-into-a#comment128279383_72619476)).

I'm struggling to figure out what seems like some basic stuff with
two lists of dates (im using momentjs). (This is for displaying specific points on a highcharts graph).

I have to go through each of the first dates, and find matching dates with the second list of dates. The issue is, I can get dates that are ***similar*** to each other, so they can be off by a bit (previously just needed to get exact (isSame) dates, but that wont work now as some dates are off by a few seconds to minutes).

I'm checking the diff between each, but I don't fully understand to ***only*** get the dates that I need.

Right now its returning every point up to the first date in the "secondDateList" (the naming is confusing, sorry)

***any ideas as to get only the matching (closest to each) dates within both lists?***

Am I right for using forEach for both arrays? I dont fully know how to only push the ***similar*** dates into a new array.

I think I should filter in the first array so I return the new array of dates that match what I want? I'm not too sure anymore..

```
const closestDatePoints: GraphPoint[] = [];
let closestPointDifference: number | null = null;

firstDateList?.forEach((firstDate, index) => {
  const formattedFirstDate = moment(firstDate[0]); // this just gets the date from this firstDate object

  secondDateList?.forEach((secondDate, index) => {
    // const isSame = date.isSame(formattedFirstDate);

    const differenceInMinutes = Math.abs(
      moment(secondDate)?.diff(formattedFirstDate, 'minutes')
    );

    if (
      closestPointDifference === null ||
      closestPointDifference > differenceInMinutes
    ) {
      closestPointDifference = differenceInMinutes;

      // I realize that this is pushing dates that I also do not 
      // want - its pushing all dates until the first, firstDate, and 
      // stopping once it hits that first firstDate. Don't know how 
      // to make it return ***only*** the dates I need.
      closestDatePoints.push(firstDate);
    }


  });
});
```

Comment: To clarify the question, you are looking for all the dates in `firstDateList` that have a matching date in `secondDateList` within some threshold right?

Comment: @gloo Yes, that's exactly it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is like finding the intersection of two arrays, except the values can be within a threshold instead of being strictly equal. Here is a naive approach that is pretty short and simple:

```
  const closestDates = firstDateList.filter((date1) =>
    secondDateList.some((date2) => Math.abs(date1.diff(date2)) < threshold)
  );
```

I have not been able to test this on real dates yet and this is far from the fastest approach, so I'm not sure if it will work for your case, but for small arrays this is pretty readable.

If you need faster performance you would need to first ensure both arrays are sorted to prevent some redundant comparisons

Comment: This actually works very well when I set a threshold, the issue is I can't use a threshold, as I need to get the "closest" date with the lowest diff - if that makes sense. However, this is a very good step forward for me because it simplifies a LOT of my code, so thank you for this.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that part of the problem. When you say "closest" date with the lowest diff, you are referring to a date in the second array, right? So your expected result array is a tuple of `(firstDate, secondDateWithLowestDiffLessThanThreshold)`? Because if your result array only consists of values from the first array, it doesn't matter whether there are multiple matching dates in the second array with some diffs lower than others, just that there is at least one matching date

Comment: No worries! Not quite - if it makes sense, your approach returns exactly what I need, a list of `firstDateList` dates that have matched "closely" to the list of dates in `secondDateList`. I should have clarified that I actually need to return `firstDateList` that match the same number of dates in the `secondDateList`array. So if there are 4 dates in the `secondDateList`, then I would have needed to return 4 `firstDateList` dates, thus, requiring 4 `firstDateList` dates that match closest to any 4 days in the `secondDateList`. Its a problematic situation, so sorry for a messy explanation

Comment: The good thing is your method helps me a lot, so I can work from there and come back with any solutions - thanks so much @gloo! What I have right now from you can work in the meantime!